# Wordpress SSL Site insecure. How do i change logo and Favicon to https?

Tags: wordpress, https

I recently updated my Wordpress site to https but i didnt get the padlock next to the name in the browser and it says that it is insercure. I investigated using the following site:

https://www.whynopadlock.com/check.php

and it appears my Logo and Favicon images are coming from a http address. Is there anyway to set these to https?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely going to find they are hard coded `http://` in your theme's header.php file.

If not, check in the customisation menu under site identity.  You may have to remove and re-add your favicon.

Comment: It is worth adding to this that you should check a site that has shifted to https in either the developer tools > console in Chrome or I am sure there is a site that will check your site to make sure all content is being called over https://   You may be surprised to find out how many http:// resources are hard coded and causing a warning.

Comment: It was not hardcoded. it has some variables there. Even after removing and adding again still gives http.

Comment: A straightforward solution is the Really Simple SSL plugin.  Works well

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  On the Settings->General page, there are two fields, "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)", that had http in them instead of https.  I update those fields and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I have found this issue today.   checked the "Wordpress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" fields and these were both showing as https://, however within the actual options table, the entries were stored with just plain http://

Updating these two fields resolved the issue.